# cURL not actually sending POST data

Tags: php, post, curl

**Overview**
I have a script, we'll call it `one.php`, that creates a database and tables. It also contains an array of data to be posted to another script, `two.php`, which will sort through the data and insert it into our newly created database.

**Your help is much, much appreciated.**

**The Problem**
`two.php` has a check for the `$_POST[]` array at the very top of the script:

```
if (empty($_POST))
{
  $response = array('status' => 'fail', 'message' => 'empty post array');
  echo json_encode($response);
  exit;
}
```

Normally, this would not be triggered unless the post array is, well, `empty()`. However, when sending the data from `one.php` to `two.php` via `cURL`, I'm receiving the above encoded array as my response, and my data does not progress further down `two.php`.

I'll lay out the relevant code from the files below for your viewing pleasure:

**one.php**

```
$one_array = array('name' => 'John', 'fav_color' => 'red');
$one_url   = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/path/to/two.php';

$response = post_to_url($one_url, $one_array, 'application/json');
echo $response; die;
```

*This is currently giving me the below:*

```
{"status":"fail","message":"empty post array"}
```

---

**The `post_to_url()` function, for reference**

```
function post_to_url($url, $array, $content_type) 
{
  $fields = '';
  foreach($array as $key => $value) 
  { 
    $fields .= $key . '=' . $value . '&'; 
  }

  $fields = rtrim($fields, '&');

  $ch = curl_init();
  $httpheader = array(
    'Content-Type: ' . $content_type,
    'Accept: ' . $content_type
  );

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $httpheader);

  $result = curl_exec($ch);

  curl_close($ch);

  return $result;
}
```

---

**two.php**

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
$response = array(); //this is used to build the responses, like below

if (empty($_POST))
{
  $response['status']  = 'fail';
  $response['message'] = 'empty post array';
  echo json_encode($response);
  exit;
}
elseif (!empty($_POST))
{
  //do super neat stuff
}
```

Comment: CURLOPT_POST should be true or false, not a count of how many things you want to post, true changing that line to `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);`

Comment: @iamde_coder, Good catch, thanks - but that does not resolve the issue. Side-note: Curiously though, the count($array) has worked for me on previous scripts. Perhaps anything 1+ returns as `true`?

Comment: pretty much, ya. what does your completed `$fields` string look like after the foreach loop and rtrim?

Comment: Using the example array above, `$fields = 'name=John&fav_color=red'`

Comment: `$httpheader` if you look closely, there are two words in this identifier, http and header, but you didn't separate them. You should do `$http_header`

Comment: @true, `$httpheader` is simply a variable.

Comment: @Benjamin instead of using the foreach and trimming why not do `http_build_query($array);` to build the query for you. I honestly can't put my finger on what's wrong with your post as it looks right, but the build query function might make that part better...

Comment: wait, where is $content_type being set and why is the curl defining the accept?

Comment: @iamde_coder The argument to `CURLOPT_POST` is defined as `long`, which means that either `true` or `1` are the same thing. That said, `CURLOPT_POST` is implied when you set `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`.

Comment: @Ja͢ck I initially had `count($array)` there *instead* of `1/true`. Good to know it is implied with `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`.

Comment: @iamde_coder I read up on it. I'm an idiot. Thanks for your help - mind making an answer post so I can give you super cool e-points?

Comment: I'm cool off the points, I'm just glad to help. Thanks though

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because you're setting the request body content type as "application/json", PHP will not populate `$_POST` in "two.php". Because you're sending url encoded data, the best thing to do is only send the `Accept:` header:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Accept: ' . $content_type]);
```

That said, "two.php" doesn't actually use the Accept: header and *always* outputs JSON; in that case, you can make do with not setting `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` at all.

#### Update

Creating url encoded data from an array can be simpler (and safer) too:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($array));
```

Comment: I'm not sure you read my question properly. I'm posting data submitted from a form to a script, which is then using cURL to post it to another script.

Comment: @Benjamin Is my answer clear now? Seems that you just accepted it for the sake of accepting ... otherwise, do let me know if there's anything unclear about it.

Comment: I went to go grab a bite to eat, but you had the issue highlighted in the first sentence. I edited your post for clarity in case others make the same mistake I did in the future. Thanks for your help!

Comment: http_build_query() helped. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I have some issue like that, but in my case I added

```
Content-Type: {APPLICATION/TYPE}
Content-Length: {DATA LENGTH}
```

and problem was solved.